# It's possible to join values of 2 datasets to create a single table in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

My problem is this:
I have 2 datasets in Google Data Studio, and I created 2 tables. The tables are identical but with a different values. It's possible to insert all values of all datasets in a single table?
Thancks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data Blending](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en) to blend two tables based on a single column or a composite key with multiple columns. However, this will only let you do a LEFT OUTER JOIN.